# Display the message entered by the user on next screen using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How to make an Edit Text on a screen so that when we press the send button it will display the message typed by user on next screen inside a text view.

I tried the following code but it gives an error message as **unresolved reference: intent2**.

1. I created two activities and named them as **MainActivity.kt** and **MessageActivity.kt** and their respective layout files as **activity_main.xml** and **activity_message.xml** .

2.Inside the activity_main.xml file I made an EditText view whose id is **etMessage** is and a button below it called send whose id is **btnSend**. This button must take the message entered by the user in the message box and send it to the next screen inside a textview of activity_message.xml whose id is **txtEmpty** and display the message in it.

so here's the code from MainActivity.kt

```
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.EditText
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        lateinit var etMessage: EditText
        lateinit var btnSend: Button
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        etMessage=findViewById(R.id.etMessage)
        btnSend=findViewById(R.id.btnSend)
        val intent2= Intent(this@MainActivity,MessageActivity::class.java)
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(){
        var message= etMessage.text.toString()
        intent2.putExtra("Message",message)
        startActivity(intent2)
        }
     }
   }
```

and the code in MessageActivity.kt is..

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class MessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var txtEmpty: TextView
    var txtMessage:String?="Message"
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message)
        txtEmpty= findViewById(R.id.txtEmpty)
        if(intent2!=null){
            txtMessage=intent2.getStringExtra("Message")
        }
        txtEmpty.text=txtMessage
    }
}
```

When I try to launch the app it's giving an error.
Can someone please explain what's wrong with my code and what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Where you're getting intent2... Just call intent.getStringExtra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually intent2 is the name of your variable in MainActivity. There is no variable named intent2 in MessageActivity.

You can reach text like this

```
txtMessage = intent.getStringExtra("Message")
```